# String codification to Twitter

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, twitter

I'm developing a program that sends tweets.
I have this piece of code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Recomendo ");
    sb.append(lblName.getText());
    sb.append(" no canal "+lblCanal.getText());

    sb.append(" no dia "+date[2]+"/"+date[1]+"/"+date[0]);
    sb.append(" às "+time[0]+"h"+time[1]);

    byte[] defaultStrBytes = sb.toString().getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
    String encodedString = new String(defaultStrBytes, "UTF-8");
```

But When I send it to tweet I get the "?" symbol or other strage characters because of the accents like "à" . I've also tried with only

```
String encodedString = new String(sb.toString().getBytes(), "UTF-8"); //also tried with ISO-8859-1
```

but the problem remains...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to read Latin-1 as UTF-8. That's why you are getting question marks.

Try to send your string as is,

```
String encodedString = sb.toString();
```

The charset should be taking care when you send the message to Tweet. If URL encoding is required, you would do something like

```
   String msg = URLEncoder.encode(encodedString, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: This solved my problem! I didn't "realised" that using OpenSearch I have to URLEncode the string... Thanks :)